# Engine Flushing

Tags: maintenance, service

At what mileage is engine flushing recommended for an engine? Some mechanics have told me that it is not needed and others insisted on its importance once the car reaches ~120,000 KM.

Cheers.

Comment: Flushing oil or coolant?

Comment: Never ask a barber if you need a haircut. It's a quick way for "mechanics" to make a profit.

Comment: Won’t need flushing at 1000km…

Answer (score 1):

Flushing is not a "routine" procedure for a normally maintained engine.  If you have an engine that has not had regular oil and filter changes then flushing may help clean it up but generally such an engine is already damaged.

As far as flushing the cooling system, same story.  If the coolant has been regularly change then there is no point.  If it's been neglected then it should be done as soon as possible.

Comment: Cheers mate, noted